# Why Large number of claims and figures are allowed and its Benefits?

Tags: patentability, claims, format

In reference to the patent: [US20120227389](https://www.google.com/patents/US20120227389)

How is it possible to apply and expect a grant with 353 claims and 545 figures?

Why They are allowed? What are benefits?

This person has granted patents but this application bewilders me.

Answer (score 1):

The patent office in the USA discourages large numbers of claims by charging extra for each independent claim greater than 3.  So the applicant must believe that there are valuable claims that are worth the extra application cost.  Of course, having too many claims makes it much more likely that the USPTO will issue a restriction requirement, forcing the applicant to choose one species of invention from among multiple inventions contained in the claim set.

Figures are also expensive to have drawn, so the applicant must believe they are helpful.  One side benefit of adding a lot of figures is that figures are the key piece in a design patent application, so if this applicant intends to get a design patent issued, lots of figures are helpful.